# spring context suppress controllers and filters

Tags: java, spring

we have a java spring web app, with heaps of controllers and filters - but we also have a bunch of unit tests.    When we run the unit tests - it's taking over two minutes to create the spring context - which makes it basically impossible to do iterative tdd.   I've noticed all the filters and controllers get autowired and initialized - is there anyway I can prevent that?   ie prevent it doing any initialization of the web side of things at all?

Comment: Why would a unit test require your spring context to be initialized? Seems like you've misunderstood the concept of a unit test.

Comment: It all depends on how you set up the context and what kind of tests you are creating. If you have "pure" unit tests, you should not need a context initialized. If you are creating integration tests you could initialize your context more selectively and not boot up everything. Again, we would need more details from you to help.

Comment: On the off-chance that you're not familiar with mocking, this might help: http://site.mockito.org/

Comment: yes - I shouldn't have called them unit tests - they are "functional" tests or "integration" tests, and they use services which autowire many many other services.